# Не сортируется массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, циклы

```
var arr = [[1487397720000,73],[1487260920000,72],[1487401320000,73],[1487268120000,73],[1487264520000,73],[1487404920000,73],[1487278920000,73],[1487271720000,72],[1487275320000,73],[1487412120000,73],[1487293320000,73],[1487282520000,72],[1487286120000,73],[1487289720000,72],[1487422920000,73],[1487311320000,72],[1487296920000,73],[1487300520000,72],[1487304120000,73],[1487307720000,73],[1487433720000,73],[1487332920000,73],[1487314920000,73],[1487318520000,72],[1487322120000,73],[1487325720000,73],[1487329320000,72],[1487444520000,73],[1487358120000,72],[1487336520000,72],[1487340120000,73],[1487343720000,73],[1487347320000,72],[1487350920000,73],[1487354520000,73],[1487595720000,73],[1487386920000,73],[1487361720000,73],[1487383320000,73],[1487379720000,73],[1487376120000,72],[1487365320000,73],[1487372520000,73],[1487368920000,73],[1487613720000,72],[1487419320000,73],[1487415720000,73],[1487390520000,73],[1487408520000,73],[1487394120000,73],[1487674920000,0],[1487440920000,72],[1487437320000,73],[1487426520000,73],[1487430120000,73],[1487682120000,0],[1487592120000,72],[1487448120000,73],[1487588520000,73],[1487700120000,72],[1487610120000,73],[1487606520000,72],[1487599320000,72],[1487602920000,73],[1487764920000,71],[1487678520000,0],[1487671320000,0],[1487631720000,72],[1487696520000,72],[1487703720000,72],[1487707320000,72],[1487768520000,72],[1487772120000,72],[1487775720000,72],[1487779320000,72],[1487782920000,71]];
arr.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a[0] > b[0]
});
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log( new Date(arr[i][0]) );
}
```

В чем проблема, почему sort не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compareFunction` должна возвращать не `boolean`, а отрицательное, нулевое или положительное значение:

```
arr.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
```